# Loading HTML templates with RequireJS

Tags: html, requirejs

I am trying to load HTML templates with RequireJS and I am trying to use a RequireJS plugin for that. https://github.com/ZeeAgency/requirejs-tpl . Here's the sample code provided in the plugin for loading a template.

```
define(['tpl!your-template-path.tpl'], function(tpl) {
    return tpl({your: 'data'});
});
```

The problem with this function is that there is no way to pass the data to this function and get the rendered html. I'm new to javascript, so please help.

And do you know of a simpler way to load HTML templates with requirejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [text](https://github.com/requirejs/text) plugin, and [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) for the templating

You use it like this:

your_template.html

```
<p>hello <%=name%><p>
```

In your requirejs file,

```
define(['underscore', 'text!./your_template.html'], function(_, yourTemplate ) {
    var compiledTemplate = _.template(yourTemplate );
    return = compiledTemplate({name: 'moe'});
});
```